# How can I counter Damage over Time?

Tags: league-of-legends

I recently played a match and ran up against [Twitch the Plague Rat](http://gameinfo.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/game-info/champions/twitch/), which seemed to do incredible amounts of damage over time.

Is there a good way, perhaps based on items, to counter damage over time in League of Legends?

Answer (score 8):

Countering damage over time, like any other damage, depends on largely what kind of damage you are taking. If, for example, you are being hurt by Teemo's [Toxic Shot](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Teemo#Toxic_Shot), then you'll want to get items with magic resist. If Talon's [Noxian Diplomacy](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Talon#Noxian_Diplomacy) is your bane, then you'll want to build more armor. Health is also a solid option if you have problems with both and you'll want to build some health anyways to enhance the effects of increased armor and/or magic resistance.

Unfortunately, building more magic resist or armor will not help against Twitch's damage over time. Twitch's [Deadly Venom](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Twitch#Deadly_Venom) deals true damage, which ignores all damage reduction from armor and magic resistance. Therefore, your only option is to build more health.

Your other option is find a way to remove the damage-over-time effect, which can only be achieved through the [Quicksilver Sash](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Quicksilver_Sash) or its upgrade, the [Mercurial Scimitar](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Mercurial_Scimitar). While the summoner spell Cleanse can clear crowd control debuffs, it *will not* remove most damage-over-time effects as they are typically not tied to crowd control effects.

Comment: Is there anything that cancels or clears the DoT?

Comment: Oh, forgot about that. Just edited my answer to include those.

Comment: I would suggest you mention health regeneration as a counter to damage over time. Items like Spirit Visage can be great against Teemo's Toxic shot. Some champions have great built in health regeneration that make using DoTs very un-effective, like Dr. Mundo with Sadism and Garen's passive Perseverance.

Comment: @C.Ross I wouldn't worry too much about removing the dot, as most champs can reapply it quickly. The few ways to clear a dot, (Mikaels Crucible [pretty sure], QSS, Mercurial Scimitar, Cleanse) have rather long cooldowns. I'd focus more on resistances as Yuki mentioned. There are exceptions of course; but, if you're new to the game these items can be difficult to use optimally.

Comment: @MichaelCapobianco Thanks!  I play support though, so doesn't it mean that cleansing/cancelling stuff should be my strong point?

Comment: @C.Ross Not really. Yes you should be trying your best to mitigate damage to your teammates (like DOTs). Most of the time you'll focus on saving your squishier, high damage dealing teammates. Abilities like Morgana's 'Black Shield' ability or Janna's 'Shield' are good for this. But your overall goals as a support are map control (Less of a support role in Season 4) and peeling for your squishy teammates. I wouldn't worry about DOT abilities, becauase they're really not going to be doing the most damage in the end. The champion that just jumped on your ADC is going to be doing the real damage.

Comment: @Yuki I think you should just break down your answer to the part where you mention Quicksilver Sash and Mercurial Scimitar, since in the first part you're basically just saying that resistances counter damage (which is always true, not just against DoT-Effects. ) - Also you could add `Zhonyas` to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

DoT are a kind of sustained damage, as opposed to burst damage.

In the end it's less about wheter you die or not, but more about how long you survive against sustained damage, for this all forms of healing help including health regeneration. Shields also help, such as that from Janna, Lulu, Tresh, Lee Sin or Shen.

Note that health regeneration, shields and heals are more effective on champs with heavy Magic Resist or Armor, since they heal the same no matter how much health you have.

Personally I found "Crystaline Flask" and "Spirit Visage" to be most effective, Crystaline Flask due to it's laughable cost, Spirit Visage due to the massive health regen + additional Magic Resistance.

For AD Carries life steal is also tremendously effective against any form of sustained damage.

If you play a Assassin health might be helpful too, so that you can get away after bursting someone with DoTs.